# Como leer una variable especifica de JSON en VB.net o C#?

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, datagridview, newtonsoft

Lo que estoy haciendo con el botón es que estoy deserializar el JSON que esta escrito en el Txt_JSONString y muestra los datos que quiero ver en un datagridview1.

Codigo del boton:

```
Private Sub Btn_Process_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_Process.Click
Tablas()
Private Sub Tablas()
        Dim json As String = Txt_JSONString.Text


        Dim rs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Root)(json)

        For Each panel In rs.Doors
            Dgv_Accessory.DataSource = panel.Accessory
            DataGridView1.DataSource = panel.Panel.Locks
        Next
    End Sub
```

para deserializar los datos cree un modulo de clases para deserializar a lista de clases. Que seria la siguiente:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class ClsJson

    Public Class Accessory
        Public Property AccessoryType As String
        Public Property AccessorySelection As String
        Public Property Quantity As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Door
        Public Property Panel As Panel
        Public Property Opening As List(Of Opening)
        Public Property DoorInfo As DoorInfo
        Public Property MiscInfo As MiscInfo
        Public Property Accessory As List(Of Accessory)
    End Class



    Public Class DoorInfo
        Public Property Type As String
        Public Property Construction As String
        Public Property HingePosition As String
        Public Property DoorInteriorFinish As String
        Public Property DoorExteriorFinish As String
        Public Property FloorType As String
        Public Property FloorEdgeThickness As Double
        Public Property FloorRecessDepth As Integer
        Public Property FloorlessTileDepth As Integer
        Public Property RoomTemperature As Integer
        Public Property IsOutdoorExposedWall As Boolean
        Public Property SwingType As String
        Public Property DrawingDescription As String
    End Class

    Public Class Lock
        Public Property Position As Position
        Public Property Edge As String
    End Class

    Public Class MiscInfo
        Public Property HardwareFinish As String
        Public Property TuffyDoor As Boolean
        Public Property SupportWheel As Boolean
        Public Property LightAboveDoor As Boolean
        Public Property PrisonPackage As Boolean
        Public Property ForceSill As Boolean
        Public Property TrackPort As Boolean
        Public Property DoorHeaters As Boolean
        Public Property FrameHeaters As Boolean
        Public Property LightExternal As Boolean
        Public Property NSFCutout As Boolean
        Public Property SSSill As Boolean
        Public Property RaiseDoor As Boolean
        Public Property HingeSpringKits As Boolean
        Public Property AddLocksToDoorOnPartitionWall As Boolean
        Public Property PRPLoc As String
        Public Property CloserLoc As String
        Public Property NumMangneticBreaks As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Opening
        Public Property ClearOpeningWidth As Integer
        Public Property ClearOpeningHeight As Integer
        Public Property OpeningCentreWidthOffset As Integer
        Public Property OpeningCentreHeightOffset As Double
    End Class

    Public Class Panel
        Public Property PanelRef As String
        Public Property PanelWidth As Integer
        Public Property PanelHeight As Integer
        Public Property PanelThickness As Integer
        Public Property InternalFinish As String
        Public Property ExternalFinish As String
        Public Property LeftDetail As String
        Public Property RightDetail As String
        Public Property TopDetail As String
        Public Property BottomDetail As String
        Public Property Locks As List(Of Lock)
    End Class

    Public Class Position
        Public Property X As Double
        Public Property Y As Integer
        Public Property Z As Double
    End Class

    Public Class Root
        Public Property Doors As List(Of Door)
    End Class

End Class
```

lo que quiero resolver es que me muestre los valores de los position X,Y,Z  junto con los Edge en un datagridview que se veria algo parecido a la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero lo que me muestra mi codigo es lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el Archivo JSON que estoy usando:

```
{
  "Doors": [
    {
      "Panel": {
        "PanelRef": "J01",
        "PanelWidth": 46,
        "PanelHeight": 82,
        "PanelThickness": 4,
        "InternalFinish": "26ga Embossed Galvalume",
        "ExternalFinish": "26ga Embossed Galvalume",
        "LeftDetail": "Groove",
        "RightDetail": "Tongue",
        "TopDetail": "Tongue",
        "BottomDetail": "Tongue",
        "Locks": [
          {
            "Position": {
              "X": 17.25,
              "Y": 2,
              "Z": 82
            },
            "Edge": "LE_Top"
          },
          {
            "Position": {
              "X": 28.75,
              "Y": 2,
              "Z": 82
            },
            "Edge": "LE_Top"
          },
          {
            "Position": {
              "X": 46,
              "Y": 2,
              "Z": 5.75
            },
            "Edge": "LE_Right"
          },
          {
            "Position": {
              "X": 46,
              "Y": 2,
              "Z": 40.25
            },
            "Edge": "LE_Right"
          },
          {
            "Position": {
              "X": 46,
              "Y": 2,
              "Z": 74.75
            },
            "Edge": "LE_Right"
          },
          {
            "Position": {
              "X": 0,
              "Y": 2,
              "Z": 5.75
            },
            "Edge": "LE_Left"
          },
          {
            "Position": {
              "X": 0,
              "Y": 2,
              "Z": 40.25
            },
            "Edge": "LE_Left"
          },
          {
            "Position": {
              "X": 0,
              "Y": 2,
              "Z": 74.75
            },
            "Edge": "LE_Left"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Opening": [
        {
          "ClearOpeningWidth": 34,
          "ClearOpeningHeight": 77,
          "OpeningCentreWidthOffset": 23,
          "OpeningCentreHeightOffset": 38.5
        }
      ],
      "DoorInfo": {
        "Type": "Flush",
        "Construction": "FRP",
        "HingePosition": "Left",
        "DoorInteriorFinish": "26ga Embossed Galvalume",
        "DoorExteriorFinish": "26ga Embossed Galvalume",
        "FloorType": "Floor_Type_1",
        "FloorEdgeThickness": 4.5,
        "FloorRecessDepth": 0,
        "FloorlessTileDepth": 0,
        "RoomTemperature": 35,
        "IsOutdoorExposedWall": false,
        "SwingType": "DS_Standard",
        "DrawingDescription": "34\" x 77\" LHH cooler door - includes V1600 hydraulic door closer with Z-1009 hook, (2) W-59 polished hinges, W-29NC latch, Locking Hasp, Weiss 24DT-SP-LT digital therm/switch, Fermod PRP & VXS100 (LED). Interior & Exterior of Door & Frame: 26ga Embossed Galvalume"
      },
      "MiscInfo": {
        "HardwareFinish": "Polished",
        "TuffyDoor": false,
        "SupportWheel": false,
        "LightAboveDoor": false,
        "PrisonPackage": false,
        "ForceSill": true,
        "TrackPort": false,
        "DoorHeaters": false,
        "FrameHeaters": false,
        "LightExternal": false,
        "NSFCutout": false,
        "SSSill": false,
        "RaiseDoor": false,
        "HingeSpringKits": false,
        "AddLocksToDoorOnPartitionWall": false,
        "PRPLoc": "PL_Standard",
        "CloserLoc": "CL_TopCentre",
        "NumMangneticBreaks": 0
      },
      "Accessory": [
        {
          "AccessoryType": "LIGHT",
          "AccessorySelection": "K-1806",
          "Quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "AccessoryType": "HINGE",
          "AccessorySelection": "W-59",
          "Quantity": 2
        },
        {
          "AccessoryType": "CLOSER",
          "AccessorySelection": "Z-1009 hydraulic",
          "Quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "AccessoryType": "LATCH",
          "AccessorySelection": "W-29NC-P",
          "Quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "AccessoryType": "PUSH_PLATE",
          "AccessorySelection": "None",
          "Quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "AccessoryType": "SWITCH",
          "AccessorySelection": "24-DT",
          "Quantity": 1
        },
        {
          "AccessoryType": "PRP",
          "AccessorySelection": "Fermod_PRP",
          "Quantity": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

}
```

Comment: Y cuál es el problema? Falla la deserialización? En cuál línea falla? Cuál es la excepción? Ya visitaste la documentación oficial?

Comment: Puedes utilizar [json2charp](https://json2csharp.com/) para crear los modelos o puedes usar NewTonSoft y utlizar `JObject` te recomiendo leer esta [documentación](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm)

Answer (score 0):

al mirar tu string json, tiene saltos de linea y espacios entre items, para que lo pueda deserializar debe ser un texto plano sin saltos de linea ni espacio entre items, a mi me rechazaba los json por ese motivo hasta que me di cuenta e hice una funcion que elimina los saltos y los espacios y hay me los deserializa sin problemas y los numeros tienen que estar entre comillas.
tu json es bastante complejo

te recomiendo que hagas un funcion que te extraiga porciones del json y asi editarlo de forma mas sencilla, por que no todos los json vienen bien construidos, por ejemplo la pagina bittrex me retorna diferentes json pero solo uno viene en el formato que se puede deserializar a los otros les falta un {}, etc.